# Dataframe convert to one row with new columns, from old row and old columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe as below and I want to convert it to one row, with new columns created from its original rows and columns,

```
data = {'Contract' : ["Team A", "Team B", "Team C"],
'Revenue': [11,7,10],
'Cost' : [5,2,9],
'Tax' : [4,2,2]}
```

like:

[image]

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df.values.flatten())
```

The result is not ideal:

```
['Team A' 5L 11L 4L 'Team B' 2L 7L 2L 'Team C' 9L 10L 2L]
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
s = df.set_index('Contract').stack().to_frame(0).T
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s
   Team A_Revenue  Team A_Cost  ...  Team C_Cost  Team C_Tax
0              11            5  ...            9           2
[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Yo! that's amazing! thank you for sharing the knowledge and guidance. all the best with your machine learnings!